# Biggest beef with game loops

Tags: events, game-engine, program-entry-point, game-loop

What do you hate most about the modern game loop? Can the game loop be improved or is there just a better alternative, such as an event-driven architecture?

Comment: Is it me, or is this more of a discussion than a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like this really ought to be a CW...

I'm taking a grad-level game engine programming course right now and they're sticking with the game loop approach.  Granted, that doesn't mean it's the only/best solution but it's certainly logical.  Using a loop allows you to ensure that all game systems get their turn to run without requesting their own timed interrupts or something else.  Control can be centralized: in my current project, I have a `GameManager` class that, each frame, loops through the `Update(float deltaTime)` function for every registered object in turn.  I don't have to debug an event system or set up timed signals, I just use a loop to call a series of functions.  No muss, no fuss.

To answer your question of what do I hate most, the loop approach does logically lend itself to liberal use of inheritance and polymorphism which can bloat the size/complexity of your objects.  If you're not careful, this can be a mild-to-horrible pitfall.  If you are careful, it may not be a problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

No matter there is any event in the game or not, game is supposed to draw itself and update it at a fixed rate, so I don't think dropping the game loop is possible. Still I would be wondered if anyone can think of any other alternative of game loop.

Comment: I was wondering if it was possible to replace it with an event-driven architecture. But I'm not sure how this would work.

Comment: -1 The game loop and render loop should not be the same loop. Otherwise, when you have a heavy period of thinking on the game loop, your animations will be froze.

Comment: @cable729 Every game is basically a event-driven architecture. The game loop is just to make sure, that game doesn't keep waiting for input forever. Consider an example of the basic Snake game. If the player is not giving any input, the snake is still supposed to move forward, which is only possible by updating the render at a fixed interval.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the event driven architectures work best for games (only do something if the user wants something done). BUT, you'll still always need to have a thread constantly redrawing the world.

Answer (score 0):

To be fully event based you could spawn an extra thread that does nothing but put a CPUTick event into your event queue every x milliseconds.

In JavaScript this is usually the more natural route, because you can so easily create an extra 'thread' that sends you the events with setInterval().

Or, if you already have a loop in the framework containing your game - like JS has in the browser, or python has with twisted - you can tell that looper to call you back at fixed intervals. e.g.:

```
function gameLoop() {
   // update, draw...
}
window.setInterval(gameLoop, 1000/fps);
```